# Preprocessor Macro not able to work as expected

Tags: xcode, target, conditional-compilation

I defined "Preprocessor Macro" FREEVERSION=0 on Main target, FREEVERSION=1 on Lite target.

then in AppDelegate

```
#ifdef FREEVERSION
@import GoogleMobileAds;
#endif
```

When I build for Lite target it runs ok. But when I build for Main target, it says error there on import.  I expect the compiler to ignore these when I select Main target. But no.Why?

Comment: `I defined "Preprocessor Macro" FREEVERSION=0 on Main target` So you _define_ it and expect a `ifdef` to be false?

Comment: I will go bury my head in the sand now. Thanks @tkausl

Comment: @tkausl if you write an answer, ill surely accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I am answering my own question. 
`#ifdef` checks for existence of the the macro. But not the value. In this case both targets have FREEVERSION defined hence evaluates to true for both. To fix it, simply remove the entry FREEVERSION=0 in Main target altogether. And the value don't matter.